# 90s cartoon TV series about a group tasked with saving children's dreams

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

I'm looking for a cartoon TV series that I watched in the late 90s. It's a cartoon about dreams, where they're monitoring children's dreams and if something is wrong, a group is tasked to save the dream.

I recall one episode about a baby's first dream and another one where a boy is asleep at school.

It's not *Captain Zed and the Zee Zone*, *The Dreamstone*, or *Midnight Patrol: Adventures in the Dream Zone*.

I just can't seem to find it.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Similar search in the web: "Rudolf, 5 years ago: ... some guy lived in a yellow place full of clouds or sheep and always had to go and save kids dreams that was bad." - does that fit your case?

Comment: Do you know what country or television channel you'd have been watching it on?

Comment: Country: Portugal
/
Channel: Canal Panda

Comment: I was about to suggest Potsworth and Co. - but it turns out "Midnight Patrol: Adventures in the Dream Zone" is the same show under a different name.

Answer (score 3):

It's maybe too early, and it's really just a segment of MLP&F instead of a show in its own right, but parts of this seem to match [*MoonDreamers*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0286371/) (1986).  It ran for 16 episodes, and featured a mixed team of fairies and animals (lions, bears) whose job it was to make sure that children had good dreams.  They had something like a control room where they could view the dreams that children were having.

[image]

Most of the conflict was with evil Queen Scowlene and her minions who wants to send everybody nightmares so they can't sleep.  I have only watched a couple of episodes, so I can't speak to the particular situations you recall, but there are some episodes where we see a child having a pleasant dream, that is ruined by Queen Scowlene's schemes but finally put right by the MoonDreamers.

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MoonDreamers) has a few more details, but you might be able to find some of the episodes [on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLLhOnau-tupQ5hHeTFsVbd__8f7Y7G67U).

Comment: No it's not that, I remember watching on tv in the late 90's, it didn't have a 80's vibe.